# Как рассчитать количество секторов,номер головки, номер дорожки и номер сектора для загрузчика?

Tags: c, ассемблер, ос, ядро, загрузчик

Как рассчитать количество секторов,номер головки, номер дорожки и номер сектора для загрузчика?

У меня есть загрузка кода :

```
mov ax,0x1100
mov es,ax
mov bx,0x00
mov ah,0x02
mov dl,1 
mov dh,0 
mov ch,0 
mov cl,2 
mov al,15
int 0x13
```

Где DL - это номер диска
DH - номер головки
CL - номер сектора
АL - количество секторов

И есть загрузка данных

```
mov ax,0x1300
mov es,ax
mov bx,0x00
mov ah,0x02
mov dl,1 
mov dh,0 
mov cl,6
mov ch,0 
mov al,1
int 0x13
```

Числа , которые сейчас стоят - не совсем верные , я пользуюсь dumpbin /headers kernel.bin и вот, что она выводит:

```
C:\Users\Elvin\source\repos\KR>dumpbin /headers kernelKR.bin
Microsoft (R) COFF/PE Dumper Version 14.12.25835.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.


Dump of file kernelKR.bin

PE signature found

File Type: EXECUTABLE IMAGE

FILE HEADER VALUES
             14C machine (x86)
               2 number of sections
        5C7ADA4B time date stamp Sat Mar  2 22:32:27 2019
               0 file pointer to symbol table
               0 number of symbols
              E0 size of optional header
             103 characteristics
                   Relocations stripped
                   Executable
                   32 bit word machine

OPTIONAL HEADER VALUES
             10B magic # (PE32)
           14.12 linker version
            1E00 size of code
             C00 size of initialized data
               0 size of uninitialized data
            1000 entry point (00011000)
            1000 base of code
            3000 base of data
           10000 image base (00010000 to 00013FFF)
            1000 section alignment
             200 file alignment
            6.00 operating system version
            0.00 image version
            6.00 subsystem version
               0 Win32 version
            4000 size of image
             200 size of headers
            6A9F checksum
               1 subsystem (Native)
             500 DLL characteristics
                   NX compatible
                   No structured exception handler
          100000 size of stack reserve
            1000 size of stack commit
          100000 size of heap reserve
            1000 size of heap commit
               0 loader flags
              10 number of directories
               0 [       0] RVA [size] of Export Directory
               0 [       0] RVA [size] of Import Directory
               0 [       0] RVA [size] of Resource Directory
               0 [       0] RVA [size] of Exception Directory
               0 [       0] RVA [size] of Certificates Directory
               0 [       0] RVA [size] of Base Relocation Directory
            3170 [      1C] RVA [size] of Debug Directory
               0 [       0] RVA [size] of Architecture Directory
               0 [       0] RVA [size] of Global Pointer Directory
               0 [       0] RVA [size] of Thread Storage Directory
               0 [       0] RVA [size] of Load Configuration Directory
               0 [       0] RVA [size] of Bound Import Directory
               0 [       0] RVA [size] of Import Address Table Directory
               0 [       0] RVA [size] of Delay Import Directory
               0 [       0] RVA [size] of COM Descriptor Directory
               0 [       0] RVA [size] of Reserved Directory


SECTION HEADER #1
   .text name
    1D01 virtual size
    1000 virtual address (00011000 to 00012D00)
    1E00 size of raw data
     200 file pointer to raw data (00000200 to 00001FFF)
       0 file pointer to relocation table
       0 file pointer to line numbers
       0 number of relocations
       0 number of line numbers
60000020 flags
         Code
         Execute Read

SECTION HEADER #2
   .data name
     A60 virtual size
    3000 virtual address (00013000 to 00013A5F)
     C00 size of raw data
    2000 file pointer to raw data (00002000 to 00002BFF)
       0 file pointer to relocation table
       0 file pointer to line numbers
       0 number of relocations
       0 number of line numbers
C0000040 flags
         Initialized Data
         Read Write

  Debug Directories

        Time Type        Size      RVA  Pointer
    -------- ------- -------- -------- --------
    5C7ADA4B coffgrp       60 00003A00     2A00

  Summary

        1000 .data
        2000 .text
```

И вот такая таблица , она приведена на картинке
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Можете рассказать, как рассчитываются такие значения ?

Comment: Поделите размер получившегося bin файла на 512 (размер сектора) с округлением вверх, получите кол-во секторов. А что касается адресации на дискете (у вас действительно есть дисковод ?) то по таблице видно, что на дорожке 18 секторов. головки всего 2 (0 и 1) данные идут по секторам дорожки одной головки, потом второй головки, после этого меняется дорожка.

Comment: https://wiki.osdev.org/ATA_in_x86_RealMode_(BIOS)